# Oracle.DataAccess.Client.BulkCopy - trying to cast varchar2 as number when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, oracle11g, odp.net

I have a table `(A)`  that includes a column named `confirmation_number`.  It is defined as a `varchar2(30)` and contains something like `SMITERI-2012-02-31-4567`.

I have another table `(B)` that also includes a column named `confirmation_number`, and it is also a `varchar2(30)`.

I have a stored procedure that extracts the data from `A`, performing some transformation on it, and it includes the confirmation number column.

I use `C#` and `ODP.Net` to run the stored procedure and load a `DataTable` with it.  I then perform some additional transformations.  However, I never touch the confirmation number column.

Finally, I create an `OracleBulkCopy` object, set the column mappings, tell it to `update` Table `B`, and call `loader.WriteToServer(dataTable)`.

**I am getting the following error**:

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt64(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy.PerformBulkCopy()
```

I have confirmed that the error occurs on the `confirmation_number` column, because if I don't load that column, the dataload succeeds.

Any ideas why the `BulkCopy` would be trying to turn a `varchar(2)` into a `Number`?

**EDIT:**
I have confirmed the following relevant issues:

1. This is happening on more than just the confirmation number.  This
   appears to only be a problem on string columns - whether from a
   string to a string or a string to an integer.
2. This doesn't happen on every varchar2 column - last name and first name have no trouble.
3. This happens both on columns that have no null values (confirmation
   number) and on columns that may have null values (street type).
4. Investigating the contents of the datatable at the moment before the
   loader begins shows no difference in column definition between those
   that successfully go in and those that do not.

I'm beginning to wonder if there's a bug in the BulkCopy itself and if I need to do this load using another utility.

**EDIT:**

Below is the trimmed down code.

**Table A**

```
  CREATE TABLE "APPS_UNPROCESSED" 
   (    "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "MIDDLE_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "NAME_SUFFIX" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "GENDER" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "DATE_OF_BIRTH" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "ID" NUMBER, 
     :
     :
    "CONFIRMATION_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "IS_FBO" NUMBER(1,0), 
     :
     :
     CONSTRAINT "VR_APPS_UNPROCESSED_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("CONFIRMATION_NUMBER")
```

**Table B**

```
  CREATE TABLE "APPS_PROCESSED"
   (    "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "MIDDLE_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "NAME_SUFFIX" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "GENDER" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "DATE_OF_BIRTH" DATE,
     :
     :
    "CONFIRMATION_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "IS_FBO" NUMBER(1,0),
     :
     :
    "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     :
     :
     CONSTRAINT "VR_APPLICATION_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
```

**Procedure**

```
 procedure getUnprocessedApps(results OUT sys_refcursor)
   as
   BEGIN
    open results for
      select 
        a.last_name
        ,a.first_name
        ,a.middle_name
        ,a.name_suffix
        ,decode(a.gender, 'M', 1, 0) as gender_id
        ,a.gender as gender_code
        ,to_char(to_date(a.date_of_birth, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-mon-YYYY') as date_of_birth
        ,cast(a.confirmation_number as varchar2(30)) as confirmation_number
        ,a.id
        ,0 as is_fbo
     :
     :
      from vr_apps_unprocessed a
```

**fetching the data**

```
            DataSet data = new DataSet();
                OracleConnection conn = null;
                OracleCommand cmd = null;
                OracleDataAdapter data_adapter = new OracleDataAdapter();


                //fetch the data and load
                using (conn = new OracleConnection(connString))
                {
                    using (cmd = new OracleCommand())
                    {

                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        cmd.CommandText = "APPS.getUnprocessedApps";
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("results", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
                        conn.Open();
                        data_adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        data_adapter.Fill(data, "results");
                    }
                }
                return data.Tables["results"];
```

**setup the column mapping**

```
 private static Dictionary<string, string> ColumnMappings()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> mapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        mapping.Add("last_name", "last_name");
        mapping.Add("first_name", "first_name");
        mapping.Add("middle_name", "middle_name");
        mapping.Add("name_suffix", "name_suffix");
        mapping.Add("gender_id", "gender"); 
        mapping.Add("date_of_birth", "date_of_birth");
        mapping.Add("is_fbo", "is_fbo"); 
        mapping.Add("confirmation_number", "confirmation_number");
        mapping.Add("id", "id"); 
     :
     :
            return mapping;
    }
```

**Load files**

```
 private static void loadFiles(DataTable dt, string connString)
        {
            OracleConnection orclconn = null;
            OracleBulkCopy loader = null;

            //now insert the data into Oracle               
            using (orclconn = new OracleConnection(connString))
            {
                orclconn.Open();
                using (loader = new OracleBulkCopy(orclconn)) 
                {
                    loader.DestinationTableName = "APPS_Processed"

                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> k in ColumnMappings())
                    {
                        loader.ColumnMappings.Add(k.Key, k.Value);
                    }

                    loader.WriteToServer(dt);

                } //end using oracle bulk loader

            } //end using oracle connection

        }
```

**EDIT:**
I have been unable to get the bulkcopy to work, but I have gotten the traditional method of using arrays to work: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-sep/o59odpnet-085168.html

It is definitely slower than a successful bulk load, but at least I can get the data in.  I'd still love if anyone has any ideas on why the bulkcopy itself keeps failing, though.

Comment: Its difficult to tell. You've detailed the steps, but without showing any code, we're not going to be able to help much.

Comment: I could show the code, but it's not at all helpful.  I'll add it in a bit - I just know that it doesn't actually tell anything about what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: okay - the code has been added.

Comment: I have not seen this issue, but just wanted to make sure you tried using 11.2.0.3. There have been bug fixes over time, so it might be worth a shot to upgrade.

Comment: Good idea - I'll check. I know I'm using v 11.2, but which release of it I'm not sure.  Might help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `BulkCopy` does some sort of type conversion based on the declared types of the columns in the `DataTable` that it is given.

If you print the `Column.DataType.ToString()` for the columns that are causing issues, there is a good chance that you will see a type other than the one which the database is expecting.

You can create a new data table from the using old one but explicitly change `Column.DataType` of the troubling columns to be of the type that the database expects.

```
public DataTable potentialFix(DataTable dt) {    
    DataTable newTable = new DataTable(dt.TableName);

    //define columns for the new table with type string (or whatever type you want)
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        newTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dc.ColumnName, typeof(String)));
    }

    newTable.BeginLoadData();
    DataTableReader dtReader = new DataTableReader(dt);
    newTable.Load(dtReader);
    newTable.EndLoadData();

    return newTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your "date_of_birth" column. you are passing a string and not a date. since dates are numbers, it tries to cast them, but it is not in a format it expect, you changed the order of months and days.

Comment: That's an idea - but what about things like the confirmation number?  That one won't go in, either.  I'll double check the dates.  But I've have learned the hard way that passing dates from .Net into Oracle has issues because they are internally represented very differently.  Instead, if I pass in a string as in the default Oracle date format (dd-mon-yyyy) it always works.

Comment: Ok - just tried it.  When my date fields are dates instead of strings, I get an "invalid date format" error.  But if I put it in as a string in the format dd-mon-yyyy, the date will go in (if I comment out all the other fields causing the issues), so that isn't it.

Comment: Another thought I had was that the datatable might not have the column names right. I think they should be case sensitive. It might also be that he discards the mapping and use the ordinal.

Comment: I'll check that - I can make everything upper case.

Comment: didn't work.  Looks like the column names are not caps sensitive - case doesn't matter when I do the array binding approach, and running the Oracle BulkCopy approach I still got the "input string is not right format" error.

Comment: Well, if you still haven't givenup I have one more idea to test. try fetching only what's needed (for example don't fetch "gender_code") and in the right order. Then try inserting.

Comment: Sorry - tried that already.  I only fetch what I need and I have them returned in the order in which the table has the columns. I'm beginning to wonder if it is somehow related to datatypes between the datatable and Oracle (e.g., "string" vs Oracle.string) combined with potential nulls.  But I may not have time to try it.  Ironically, I use this approach for lots of other processes, but this one it just won't work.  But it is the only one which has null values and the only one which has dashes in some fields.